# screen is called two times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, c#-5.0

I have this:

View:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>EDIT</h2>


<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Personal information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">The Bike</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">


        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Lola Biker</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)



                <form class="form-horizontal">

                    @Html.ActionLink("Change your password", "Manage")


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Motto, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Motto, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlaceOfBirth, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PlaceOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HowManyBikes, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HowManyBikes, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BesideYourBeth, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BesideYourBeth, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NicestRide, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NicestRide, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorstRide, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorstRide, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AmountKmPerYear, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountKmPerYear, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AverageSpeed, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AverageSpeed, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AbleToChatWhileRiding, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AbleToChatWhileRiding, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
                    </div>




                </form>


                <br />


                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <br /><br />
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>




    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="tabs-2">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))

            //new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <h4>Photos</h4>
                    <hr />

                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                    <form class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayItem)

                        </div>

                        <div id="upload-choices">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-row">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">

                                <tr>
                                    <th><img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id = Model.Id })"></th>


                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="Find file">


                    </form>

                    <br />
                    <div class="progress progress-striped">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="status"></div>


                    <br />

                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Upload photos", "Upload")*@
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Id" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            }

            <br /><br />
            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>

        </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        Content for Tab 3 goes here.<br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>

</div>
    </div>




<br /><br />
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#tabs").tabs();
            //    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
            //        $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);

            //        $(":file").filestyle({ size: "sm" });
            //        $(":file").filestyle({ buttonText: "Find file" });              
            //});
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var percent = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                success: function () {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        })();       
    </script>
}
```

and controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");

             }
            return PartialView(userprofile);       

        }
```

it goes about tab2

but after I put on save, the view was rendering two times, so I put a breakpoint on this line:

`user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];`, I get the messagee:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ContosoUniversity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. file = null
```

but if I after continue, then it loops again and saves the file to database. But so the first time is file = null, but if I continue the file is saved, but also the view is now showing correctly after saving the image.

Thank you

Before uploading

[image]

after uploading:

[image]

oke, I made it minimal. See this:

View:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>EDIT</h2>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <input type="file" name="file"><br>
                <input type="submit"  value="Upload File to Server">
            }

<div class="progress progress-striped">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
</div>

<div id="status"></div>

            <br /><br />
            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>

<br /><br />
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>



        $(document).ready(function () {


            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var percent = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#status')



            $('form').ajaxForm({


                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                success: function () {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        })();       
    </script>
}
```

Controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account"));

             }
            return View(userprofile);       

        }
```

but still it looks like this, after uploading image:

[image]

Comment: Difficult to tell because you have a few potential issues. Most obvious is that you have nested forms which is not supported. I'm not familiar with the jquery form plugin you using but it must support file uploads (otherwise the file would never be uploaded). Perhaps it is first submitting the inner form (which does not include the file) then submitting the outer form.

Comment: Have you got rid of the nested forms? Has it made any difference?

Comment: ? NO, you dont see the new picture I uploaded? it is still the same result :(

Comment: I Just dont understand why it is?